# Move portlets inside nested-portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I added a nested-portlet inside my page. This nested-portlet is a 2-column 50-50 layout. I am able to insert a portlet inside that, but I can't insert one next to another one, although the layout of the nested-portlet has two columns.

Is there anything I am missing?

[image: Nested-portlet Configuration]

[image: Unable to move portlet next to another one]

**EDIT**: Ok, there is a problem related to the custom theme used. If I set the default theme of Liferay, the problem disappears.

**SOLVED**: The problem was that the theme I installed forced the portlet divs to be *display: block;*. I changed that as *display:table-cell* and the problem disappeared.

Comment: So based on the edit, you are all set?

Answer (score 0):

Check HTML well-formedness of the page generated by your custom theme. I expect the structure to be broken - for example an unclosed `div` element may prevent the portlet dropping from working.